# Angular HostListener catch only one event

Tags: angular, scroll

I'm using HostListener to load the next bunch of data on scroll but when I scroll to the bottom the HostListener is called many times so all of the data is loaded. How to call it only once when reaching the bottom of page?

```
  @HostListener('document:scroll', [])
  onScroll() {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY * 1.1) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      //loading next 20 records 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired behavior you need to debounce your check until the user has stopped scrolling and then check the scroll position for the end of the page.

I would suggest to debounce the calcuation either with `setTimeout` or RxJS.

**Option `setTimeout`**

```
private timeoutID: number;

@HostListener('document:scroll', [])
onScroll() {

  if (timeoutID) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }
  
  // Delay execution for e.g. 300ms 
  setTimeout(() => {
    // Checks for end of page
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY * 1.1) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
      //loading next 20 records 
    }
  }, 300);
}
```

As soon as the user stop scrolling for at least 300ms the latest `setTimeout` becomes executed.

**Option `RxJS`**

```
private subs: Subscription;

ngOnInit(){
  this.subs = fromEvent(document, 'scroll').pipe(

    // Delay execution by 300ms after the last event
    debounceTime(300),

    // Prevent execution of the subscription as long as the page end isn't reached
    filter(() => (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY * 1.1) >= document.body.offsetHeight)

  ).subscribe(() => {
    // Load the next 20 records
  });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  this.subs.unsubscribe();
}
```

As soon as the user stops scrolling for at least 300ms the subscription becomes executed only if the page end is reached.

I showed both approaches for completeness but personally I would recommend the `RxJS` way since I think this approach is cleaner than the other.

Comment: thank you, this aproach delays an event but it is also called multiple times so all of my data is loaded

Comment: Which approach have you tried? Either way it seems weird, please share your code :)